# Where is representative data placed in the MVP or MVC pattern?

Tags: oop, model-view-controller, mvp

In the MVP and MVC pattern you want to clearly separate the View from the Model.

But to display stuff like Icons, Animations that should play when something happens etc., the Model needs to tell the View how it wants to be represented. For example the icon on a button that selects an element.

Thus I think that stuff like Images, Animation Frame Data etc. should be part of the Model as the elements of the Model need to define this. But I also feel like this should not be the case. As such the only thing I can imagine is having a huge Mapping stored somewhere that maps types of the model to representative data. That seems like a huge anti-pattern to me.

How would you structure this stuff in a project? Where is the data of "how should it look" be stored? Inside the Model, inside the Presenter (a Mapping) or inside the View (a Mapping). Maybe I am missing something crucial here.

To clarify where this is coming from:

Consider you have objects that get represented by icons in a list. These objects all have a common supertype but each differ in details and thus should be represented by different icons. Moreover, maybe you implemented everything as a common type and define it's whole behavior just during construction or setting stuff up during runtime, so you do not even have a way to differentiate between icons to display via type. As such I would deem these objects need an accessor like "getImage" to get the representation they would like to have in the GUI. But having the image be part of the model seems wrong.

To present a common way to form an answer, the imaginary project may be structured in the following directories:

```
src/model/
src/view/
src/presenter/
```

Where would each type/class with what methods be located?

Answer (score 2):

> How would you structure this stuff in a project? Where is the data of
>   "how should it look" be stored?

This is where I use a `ViewModel`.  You map your `Model` to the `ViewModel` and use the `ViewModel` to represent what properties get displayed.  You can tailor the `ViewModel` to:

- Style/css the property,
- Combine properties,
- Validation logic,
- Change how the property is displayed and more.

> Where would each type/class with what methods be located?

*src/viewModel*

Comment: Would classes of the model then subtype the Viewmodel or are Viewmodel objects containers that are managed by the presentation layer?

Comment: No subtypes.  Your models should be mapped to viewmodels 1 to 1.  They are presentation layer objects ("view"model) :)

Comment: So are they containers (or rather "decorators") of the model or are they really stored in a map from ModelObject A to ViewObject B and accessing A from B happens via the map in reverse (like applying whatever means clicking on a button)?

Comment: @salbeira...It's like, what and how to display your model's properties.  One model to one viewModel.  The model is mapped to the viewModel and the viewModel is what is bound to your View - not the Model.